# Python: How do I find the first letter of a string?

Tags: python, string, slice, indices

For example, if I had the string **thisisastring** how could I find the first character? Is there an easy way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean how to get 't' from 'thisisastring'?

Comment: @Robbie, it's not really a duplicate. `s[0]` and `s[:3]` are different.

Comment: @smci Probably not the best "duplicate" example to use, but it's there plenty of times where, with a minimal amount of searching here (or googling) the answer would appear or could easily be deduced.

Comment: @Robbie: I'm saying that surprisingly and shockingly, there is no canonical existing answer for the actual question "How do I find the first letter of a string? in Python". (There's lots of other stuff which implicitly includes it.) So if there isn't any canonical question, this one will and should become the canonical answer.

Comment: @smci: Fair enough. I'll remove the close vote.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you:

```
string = "thisisastring"
print(string[0])

# output: t
```

More on this topic in the [String documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Comment: i think it would be good idea to suggest @Alex to check official [string documentaion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)